# How should you work with Themes in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-theme

I have been practising my skills with android (Kotlin), and I am having issues with styling the UI, with most solutions here not working. It feels like there's some default style overriding what I am trying to achieve because often than not the changes are visible in the layout creator GUI in android studio but not in the app itself. I even noticed the apps base dark or light theme setting affects the Ui looks which should not be the case for me.

The greatest challenge I have had is trying to change the app theme with both methods not working or working only to a certain degree which often leaves things quite off:

toggling using this `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

or explicitly changing the theme using `setTheme(R.style.Theme_Dark)`

Is there something I am not considering or I do not know? I am happy to provide any more information for better context. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I have done a little more reading and seen some of the underlining issues I was experiencing. I'll be updating this are I learn more.

1. I have learned of a feature called [Force Dark](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force-dark) introduced in Android 10 which automatically intelligently inverts the colours of the screen ignoring elements such as images and icons vectors in order to create a dark theme before the view is rendered.

Adding this line in more Theme xml file prevented this giving me more freedom.

```
 <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

**(27-6-2022)**